# Loading into appropriate child with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I use drop-down selector to load matching section from an external file into the table cell in a row below selector. I can't seem to be able to target it properly. I thought that nextAll() would do the trick but it doesn't. What else shall I try?

```
$('.mySelector').change(function(){
    var $selectForm = '#' + $(this).val();
    $(this).nextAll('.fLoad').load('formParts.html ' + $selectForm );
});

<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <select class="mySelector">
       <option value="o1">Car details</option>
       <option value="o2">Bike details</option>
       <option value="o3">Boat details</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='fLoad'>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <select class="mySelector">
       <option value="o1">Car details</option>
       <option value="o2">Bike details</option>
       <option value="o3">Boat details</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='fLoad'>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: You need to determine if the load is failing of the DOM traversal. Change the line to `$(this).nextAll('.fLoad').text('found it')` to check that you are finding the right element.

Comment: No, it does not seem like it finds the target...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next().find('.fLoad').load('formParts.html ' + $selectForm );
```

- use the [`closest()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to get the nearest ancestor `<tr>` element.
- the [`next()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method to traverse to the next `<tr>` element
- the [`find()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to find the `.fLoad` element

Comment: Hmm... can't seem to be able to hit it... Is there a way to highlight which section I hit, in order to test?

Comment: Got it! I forgot I had another class in that <td>. I combined the two and it works great! Thanks.